# Pyspark : How to calcul arccos, arcsin, arctan in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

In the Dataframe, I want to compute the arccos, arcsin, arctan in the dataframe :
For exemple :

| Angle A | arccos A | arcsin A | arctan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 |  |  |  |
| 15 |  |  |  |
| 45 |  |  |  |
| 60 |  |  |  |

Please, I want to compute for each angle of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import `pyspark.sql.functions` where you will find `acos()`, `asin()` and `atan()`